# How exactly does the possessive quantifier work?

Tags: java, regex, greedy, quantifiers

At the end of the page there is at attempted explanation of how do greedy, reluctant and possessive quantifiers work: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

However I tried myself an example and I don't seem to understand it fully.

I will paste my results directly:

```
Enter your regex: .*+foo
Enter input string to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
No match found.

Enter your regex: (.*)+foo
Enter input string to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
I found the text "xfooxxxxxxfoo" starting at index 0 and ending at index 13.
```

Why does the first reg.exp. find no match and the second does?
What is the exact difference between those 2 reg.exp.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` after another quantifier means "don't allow the regex engine to backtrack into whatever the previous token has matched". (See a tutorial on [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) here).

So when you apply `.*foo` to `"xfooxxxxxxfoo"`, the `.*` first matches the entire string. Then, since `foo` can't be matched, the regex engine backtracks until that's possible, achieving a match when `.*` has matched `"xfooxxxxxx"` and `foo` has matched `"foo"`.

Now the additional `+` prevents that backtracking from happening, so the match fails.

When you write `(.*)+foo`. the `+` takes on an entirely different meaning; now it means "one or more of the preceding token". You've created nested quantifiers, which is not a good idea, by the way. If you apply that regex to a string like `"xfoxxxxxxxxxfox"`, you'll run into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Your answer has given me more than I asked for. I think this explains everything there is to know about quantifiers.

Comment: @Ariel: Thanks, but there's a lot more to quantifiers than this :)

Comment: Like what? What else should I know about quantifiers?

Comment: @Ariel: The difference between lazy and greedy matching is very relevant, for example. Then, there are `*`, `+`, `?` and `{n,m}` to choose from, each of which can be made possessive or lazy. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

Answer (score 0):

The possessive quantifier takes the **entire** string and checks if it matches, if not it fails. In your case xfooxxxxxxfoo matches the `.*+` but then you ask for *another* `foo`, which isn't present, so the matcher fails.

The greedy quantifier first does the same, but instead of failing it "backs off" and tries again:

```
xfooxxxxxxfoo fail
xfooxxxxxxfo fail
xfooxxxxxxf fail
xfooxxxxxx match
```

In your second regex you ask for something else by confusing the grouping mechanism. You ask for "one or more matches of (.*)" as the + now relates to the () and there is one match.